# how to covert an exception to a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am logging any errors in my code, I have tried using:

```
try:
    #some deliberately dodgy code
Except Exception:
    print(Exception) #i am actually passing this to a function to add it in a file
```

but all I am getting is: <class 'Exception'>

Comment: `except Exception as e:  ;  print(e)`

Comment: Exception is a class. In the except clause, you should have `Exception as e` in order to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    #some deliberately dodgy code possibly involving pig's head (ask dodgy Dave)
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
```

`exc` is not a string (it's an exception object) but `print` will call its `__str__` method which will return the message string with which it was instantiated

(you don't need to call it `exc`, you can call it anything you like, but `exc` or `e` are quite commonly used)

If you want the message in a variable you can always do explicitly

```
message = str(exc)  # now it really is a string
```

inside the `except` block

Answer (score 0):

Exception is a class, you should make an object inherited from Exception, like this:

```
try:
    #some deliberately dodgy code
Except Exception e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually on the right track, but your code should look instead as follows.

```
try:
    #some deliberately dodgy code
except Exception as message:
    print(message)
```

You can take a look at this post, [**Converting Exception to a string in Python 3**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075200/converting-exception-to-a-string-in-python-3), for more details and deeper understanding.